# How to customize the filter editor of a devexpress GRID.CONTROL for WPF?

Tags: c#, xaml, grid, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

We are using a Dx GridControl for WPF, and we want to customize the filter editor popup dropdown list in order to add additional columns to the list , like shown in the attached image. this will help us to create filters with fields not shown in the GridControl.

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks.

Medi

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachment?fileOid=2c9cfd9a-aaa4-11e3-80be-00155d624701&fileName=FilterEditorsDropDownListFields.png

Answer (score 0):

To customize the Fitler Editor before it is displayed, handle the [DataViewBase.FilterEditorCreated](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument7788) event. You can find more information in [this article](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument7788).

**Update**

To add new columns you can user [FilterColumns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsFilteringFilterControl_FilterColumnstopic) property, but for that you should use unbound mode (without SourceControl).

Comment: We already do that, but we don't know which property is used to customize the drop-list in the Filter-editor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i tried and didn't found how to use the Unbound mode ! some says that i must use the treelist view for that. So if you can clarify this to me, or give me a code sample for it. this will be very helpfull !               Thanks.